# How to write a program for ARM using *only* assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I would like to write a small program in pure ARM assembly for my ARM-based phone (Nexus S).
I know about inline assembly in C, but when i tried a simple program such as

```
int main() {
    asm("nop");
    return 0;
}
```

perf showed that thousands of instructions and cycles were consumed to run this program.
I'm not sure why..but I believe this is because of loading the minimum C library so as to handle int main and return 0 among other things.
I would like to avoid that..

So, I was wondering if it is possible to write a small program in pure assembly and execute it on an ARM-based phone(Nexus S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need some proper toolkit - most importantly assembler. I would suggest [fasmarm](http://arm.flatassembler.net).

It is crossassembler based on FASM - you should write your programs on x86 machine - Windows or Linux, compile the program and then upload it to the Arm machine for execution.

[Fasmarm](http://arm.flatassembler.net) supports the full range of Arm processors and coprocessors.

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst - You are wrong. (And thus it is good you can't vote down ;) ) FASM assembler is for Intel programming. FASMARM is a branch of FASM, uses the same code base, has the same syntax of the preprocessor and data definition directives, but compiles for ARM processors. That is why it is named FASM**ARM**. Of course, it is cross-compiler. FASMARM runs on Intel machines, but compiles for ARM.

Answer (score 1):

```
.globl _start
_start:
   nop
   b .
```

Comment: Could you suggest some place where I can learn to write plain assembly like this?

Comment: Isn't the entry point of a NDK-based app somewhere in Java-land and the native code called via JNI?

Guess if you rooted the phone there's no problem with installing console apps though.

Comment: @Marko: The NDK allows you to develop apps with only native activities, where your apk won't contain any Java code at all. That's not to say that no Java code in Android is involved in launching your app. And it's not going to be "bare metal" assembly coding anyway.

Comment: Ironically, you probably can build a minimal, assembly only app for iOS, with a method not dissimilar to that proposed by @Dwelch provided you run it from XCode's debugger....  However, the think if the OP really wants to try this, a Raspberry Pi is probably the device of choice.

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67 I have simulators for different instruction sets geared towards learning asm and bare metal that may or may not be useful to you.  I agree with Marko, I recommend using instruction set simulators first then moving to hardware like the raspberry pi or a list of others in the $10 to $20 range.  Your phone nor laptop/desktop are the right place (phone for its environment, laptop/desktop because if it is x86 that is NOT a good first assembly language).

Comment: I imagine the phone environment has some sort of system call to end a program the above trivial example has an infinite loop at the end (b . means branch to this line, or branch to self), so the above program may not really do you much good, to "see" anything in a program like that you would need an environment, debugger, jtag, etc.  Much easier to learn and see in a simple simulator where you can control or change the output to see what is going on...

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will probably get myself a Raspberry Pi and work on this. I'm basically trying to identify the size of the instruction cache programmatically..since writing this in C adds a lot of libraries and instructions, I decided to try and do it in assembly itself..since I had an ARM based phone to test on..

Comment: You only need two CP15 operations to read the cache size on Cortex-A15, I think.  Why do you want to write the whole program in assembly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use duo **gnu arm** compiler + **eclipse** IDE. To have full environment you need also bootloader. Because I had to deal with LPC2148 uC, I used to use LPCUSB loader. It was also easy to integrate with eclipse... so loading and compiling did one-click.

More information you will find using: 
https://www.google.pl/search?num=20&newwindow=1&safe=off&espv=210&es_sm=93&q=gnu+arm+eclipse+plugin+installation

You have to choose proper bootloader that will be working with your uC.